# Upgrading pip on mac

Tags: python, pip

I'm trying to upgrade pip on my mac using this command

`pip install --upgrade pip`

After I enter that command I get this error

`zsh: command not found: pip`

I also can't even seem to get the version of pip when I enter this

`pip --version`

I get the same error.

I am new to this and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. It is possible the fact that I'm using `zsh` but honestly, I'm pretty sure I changed to `zsh` when installed `homebrew` but I forget what `zsh` even means for me.

Comment: did you install python using homebrew?

Comment: try `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

I solved my issue by using `pip3 install --upgrade pip` to upgrade to the latest version of pip. Now install using `pip install` works fine.

I'm not sure why I had to use `pip3` but it works now.

Comment: You need to use ```pip3``` because you have an installation of Python ```2.x``` on your computer. So when you type ```pip <command>```, the system doesn't know which version of Python you want. Hence, you need to specify ```pip3```.